# Animating an image in framer motion

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I'm trying to animate an image using framer motion in react

```
<div className={classes.imgContainer}>
    <img src={gradient} id={classes["gradient"]} alt="gradient" />
    <motion.img
       id={classes["floater"]}
       initial={{ y: -10 }}
       animate={{ y: 10 }}
       transition={{
         type: "smooth",
         repeatType: "mirror",
         duration: 2,
         repeat: Infinity,
       }}
       src={floaterImg}
       alt="floater"
    />
</div>
```

But the code above throws TypeError: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'needsInterpolation')"

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue after upgrading to next 13. Fixed it by upgrading to the latest version of framer-motion.